# Custom Editors for custom typed properties for a Model in MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working with some business objects that relate to one another through their properties. For instance I am loading an "Entry" object from the data store and relating it to "User" objects through the Author and Editor properties.

```
class Entry{
    public User Author { get; set; }
    public User Editor { get; set; }
}

class User{
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a new Entry object using MVC2, I want to supply a drop down that has a list of the available users. I am lost as to what way would be best.

Right now I am going down the path of using EditorFor calls, but it has its issues. For example, I can do the following:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author) %>
```

And then create an view control under Shared/EditorTemplates that presents it as a dropdown (possible?) but this seems like it would corrupt all edits of the User class. For instance if I attempt to edit a User object directly, I want to be able to update the fields associated with that class. So I need the editor templates to be context sensitive.

I also attempted to go down the route of manual form creation:

```
<%= Html.DropDownFor(model => model.Author, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Users"]) %>
```

But this seemed messy and I am confused as to how the values get serialized back into a User object from SelectListItem.

Any help is appreciated. I am sure this problem has been covered before, but I had trouble getting much of any information out of my queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend strongly-typed Views and EditFor.  It's much easier to maintain and test.

It sounds like you need to start using ViewModels.  ViewModels are an abstraction between the View and the Model, so that the View does not interact directly with the Model, which can lead to issues as you have discovered.

A ViewModel is sometimes just a "wrapper" around the actual Model.  Using your Entry class as an example, a ViewModel for that might be `EntryViewModel`.  It could have an `Entry` property, as well as supporting related data you want to display.  The important thing is that the ViewModel contains *only* data need by the View it supports, nothing more.

Suppose you wanted users to be able to update the `Entry.Author` property from the Entry View- you could populate the `EntryViewModel` with a list of IDs and names from the `Authors` entity/table.

Comment: This sounds reasonable enough. However, in practice I am having some issues. It seems that I have it going one way (into the view) but am having trouble getting it back out of the view after the submit button is pressed.

I get the following error: "The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'TestComplexCreates.Models.User' failed because no type converter can convert between these types." This is understandable since the dropdown shows strings, not complex types. Any thoughts on what I am missing?

Comment: I decided to go this route simply because there doesn't seem to be another way. Eventually the model has to be boiled down to simple types. Frustrating to say the least.

Comment: You can make it less frustrating by looking into T4 templates.  T4 templates can cook up ViewModels based on your Entity Model.